# Passing data from page to page loads previous data until page refresh

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a button that when clicked passes data to another page using session state but it loads data from previous transactions on first load instance. it is after a refresh that the current data is loaded. I have searched for solutions to similar problems but I have not got one that solved this for me.

**button code**

```
Protected Sub LinkButton9_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkButton9.Click
    'LinkButton9.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('waterprinter.aspx','','height=530,width=530');return false")
    'LinkButton9.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('waterprinter.aspx', '','height=530,width=530','scrollbars=yes','tools=1');return false")


    Dim queryString As String = ""
    Dim SBRANCH As SqlDataReader
    Dim Pdate As Date
    Dim TRN As String = ""
    Dim PaymentFor As String = ""
    Dim CustomerName As String = ""
    Dim CustomerRef As String = ""
    Dim AmtDue As Double = 0
    Dim AmtPaid As Double = 0
    Dim ServedBy As String = ""
    Dim Branch As String = ""

    Try

        If Session("PayID") <> Nothing Then

            Dim MyReader As SqlDataReader
            Dim MyReaderI As SqlDataReader
            Dim MyReaderII As SqlDataReader
            MyReader = dat.DBAction("SELECT * FROM NSSFPaymentsArchive WHERE Authorized = 1 and Status = 'Posted' and PaymentID = " & Session("PayID") & "", DataManagement.DBActionType.DataReader)
            If MyReader.HasRows Then
                MyReader.Read()
                Session("TRN") = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("ReferenceNumber")), "", MyReader("ReferenceNumber")) '"50000.00"
                Session("PaymentFor") = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("PaymentName")), "", MyReader("PaymentName"))
                Session("Pdate") = FormatDateTime(Date.Today, DateFormat.ShortDate)
                Session("CustomerName") = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("CustomerName")), "", MyReader("CustomerName"))
                Session("CustomerRef") = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("CustomerRefNumber")), "", MyReader("CustomerRefNumber")) ' "Ura cash A/c"
                AmtDue = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("AmountDue")), "", MyReader("AmountDue")) ' "
                AmtPaid = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("AmountPaid")), "", MyReader("AmountPaid"))
                Session("AmtDue") = Format(Val(AmtDue - AmtPaid), "#,#.00")
                Session("AmtPaid") = Format(AmtPaid, "#,#.00")
                Session("PaymentOption") = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("PaymentOption")), "", MyReader("PaymentOption"))
                Session("Narration") = dat.SpellNumber(Val(AmtPaid), "Shilling")
                Session("Teller") = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("CapturedBy")), "", MyReader("CapturedBy"))
            Else
                MyReader.Close()
                MyReader = dat.DBAction("SELECT * FROM NSSFPayments WHERE  paymentid = " & Session("PayID") & "", DataManagement.DBActionType.DataReader)
                If MyReader.HasRows Then
                    MyReader.Read()
                    Session("TRN") = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("ReferenceNumber")), "", MyReader("ReferenceNumber")) '"50000.00"
                    Session("PaymentFor") = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("PaymentName")), "", MyReader("PaymentName"))
                    Session("Pdate") = FormatDateTime(Date.Today, DateFormat.ShortDate)
                    Session("CustomerName") = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("CustomerName")), "", MyReader("CustomerName"))
                    Session("CustomerRef") = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("CustomerRefNumber")), "", MyReader("CustomerRefNumber")) ' "Ura cash A/c"
                    AmtDue = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("AmountDue")), "", MyReader("AmountDue")) ' "
                    AmtPaid = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("AmountPaid")), "", MyReader("AmountPaid"))
                    Session("AmtDue") = Format(Val(AmtDue - AmtPaid), "#,#.00")
                    Session("AmtPaid") = Format(AmtPaid, "#,#.00")
                    Session("PaymentOption") = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("PaymentOption")), "", MyReader("PaymentOption"))
                    Session("Narration") = dat.SpellNumber(Val(AmtPaid), "Shilling")
                    Session("Teller") = IIf(IsDBNull(MyReader("CapturedBy")), "", MyReader("CapturedBy"))
                End If
            End If
            MyReader.Close()

            MyReaderI = dat.DBAction("select branchname from branches where solid='" & Session("branch") & "'", DataManagement.DBActionType.DataReader)
            If MyReaderI.HasRows Then
                MyReaderI.Read()
                Session("PayBranch") = MyReaderI("branchname")
            End If
            MyReaderI.Close()

            MyReaderII = dat.DBAction("select FULLNAME from USERS where USERNAME='" & Session("Teller") & "'", DataManagement.DBActionType.DataReader)
            If MyReaderII.HasRows Then
                MyReaderII.Read()
                Session("ServedBy") = MyReaderII("FULLNAME")
            End If
            MyReaderII.Close()


        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

**code for the page the data is moved to (second page)**

Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
    lblTRN.Text = Session("TRN")
    lblPaymentFor.Text = Session("PaymentFor")
    lblPaymentDate.Text = Session("Pdate")
    lblCustomerName.Text = Session("CustomerName")
    lblCustomerRefNo.Text = Session("CustomerRef")
    lblAmountDue.Text = Session("AmtDue")
    lblAmountPaid.Text = Session("AmtPaid")
    lblServedBy.Text = Session("ServedBy")
    lblBank.Text = "IMPERIAL BANK"
    lblBranch.Text = Session("Branch")
    Label2.Text = Session("Narration")


End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Data is updated in DB before second page is loaded ?

Comment: No, instead data is got from db before second page is loaded.

Comment: And from where you are redirecting to second page ?

Comment: From that linkbutton9..when that button is clicked ..there is a redirect to the second page.

Comment: I don't see any code for the redirect. Also, you could refactor your code to use an object to store all these values rather than set them individually. Finally, could you attach the load() method of the second page?

Comment: The load method is attached above(Page_Load method). tenx.

Comment: Are you clearing the session(s) to Nothing once you have finished with them on the second page? If not then visiting the first page will reuse the data as the session is not nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed It was executing the pageload logic before the executing the logic on the button click. So I put the logic I had on button click to another function that I called on page load of the second page. I made sure I called the function before anything on page load of the second page and it worked. Thanks for your contributions.